# Dynamically Create Folders and Subfolders

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have several scripts in php to create a folder and upload a file to the desired folder, but I can't seem to be able to create new folders, new subfolders or create another function to do this process. Do i have to use a parent/children specific procedure? Here's the functional code I use to create a folder:

```
function getFolderExistsCreate($service, $folderName, $folderDesc) {
// Lista el root de drive
$files = $service->files->listFiles();
$found = false;

// Checa los folders en ciclo
foreach ($files['items'] as $item) {
    if ($item['title'] == $folderName) {
        $found = true;
        return $item['id'];
        break;
    }
}

// Lo crea si no lo encontro
if ($found == false) {
    $folder = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();

    //Poner los settings del folder
    $folder->setTitle($folderName);

    if(!empty($folderDesc))
        $folder->setDescription($folderDesc);

    $folder->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');

    //Try de crear el folder
    try {
        $createdFile = $service->files->insert($folder, array(
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
            ));

        // Regresa el nuevo id del folder
        return $createdFile->id;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

Help please, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a subfolder to a particular folder, you should specify the correct ID in the `parents` property of the file.

```
"parents": [{"id":"0ADK06pfg"}]
```

Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder) for more information

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the parent id of the folder you want to place it in.

code from [files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)

```
// Set the parent folder.
  if ($parentId != null) {
    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
  }
```

Eastest way to get the folder id is to do a [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) use the q search option to search for folders only `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` then you can find the folder you want to place you new folder or file into.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the class Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference() doesn't work anymore.. Use this:

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        //Set the Random Filename
        'name' => $rdmName,
        //Set the Parent Folder
        'parents' => array('0BzaRxkCDivjIM1pUYU1SLWVxOGM')
    ));


    try{


        $newFile = $drive_service->files->create(
            $fileMetadata,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents(TESTFILE),
                'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
                'uploadType' => 'media'
            )
        );


    } catch(Exception $e){

        echo 'An error ocurred : ' . $e->getMessage();

    }
```