# subfolder Creation in google drive (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api, directory, subdirectory

I want to create a folder with a subfolder in google drive using vb.net. 
I managed to create the folder , but not the subfolder.

Here is my code

```
 Public Sub createfolder()
 Dim dossier = New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
    dossier.Title = dat_sauv.SelectedItem 'title from combobox in forms
    dossier.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    Dim rep = Service.Files.Insert(dossier)
    rep.Fields = "id"
    Dim file = rep.Execute()
    'sub folder Creation
    Dim subfolder = New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
    'title from radio button in forms
    If (VT.Checked = True) Then
        subfolder.Title = VT.Text
    ElseIf (vm.Checked = True) Then
        subfolder.Title = VM.Text
    ElseIf (VI.Checked = True) Then
        subfolder.Title = VI.Text
    Else
        subfolder.Title = VF.Text
    End If
    subfolder.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    Dim res = Service.Files.Insert(subfolder)
    res.Fields = "id"
    Dim fil = res.Execute()
    dossier.Parents = subfolder
    end sub
```

any help please

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253909/google-drive-api-create-sub-folders), you should have first a `parents` folder. You need to search for the parent root ID. The [`parents`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder) property can be used when creating a folder as well to create a subfolder.

Here's a related posts:

- [Dynamically Create Folders and Subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087112/dynamically-create-folders-and-subfolders)

  > To create a subfolder to a particular folder, you should specify the
  >   correct ID in the `parents` property of the file.
  >
  > ```
  > "parents": [{"id":"0ADK06pfg"}]
  > ```
  >
  > Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder) for
  >   more information
- [How can I create a new folder with Google Drive API in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558653/how-can-i-create-a-new-folder-with-google-drive-api-in-python)

  > You only need a parent ID here if you want to create folder within another folder, otherwise just don't pass any value for that.
  >
  > If you want the parent ID, you'll need to write a method to search Drive for folders with that parent name in that location (do a list() call) and then get the ID of that folder.

Hope this helps!